# Best practice for controlling QML?

Tags: c++, qt, controller, qml

I have this **login.qml** window in which I have a controller declared as follows:

```
Button {
    id: btnOK
    anchors.top:senhaInput.bottom
    anchors.left: senhaInput.left
    anchors.topMargin: 10
    width: (senhaInput.width * 0.60) - 5
    text: "Entrar"
    isDefault: true
    onClicked: {
        lblMsgErro.text = ""
        lblMsgErro.visible = false;
        controller.autenticar();
    }
}

QLoginController {
    id: controller
    login: loginInput.text
    senha: senhaInput.text

    onAuthenticated: {
        if (userId) {
            console.log("Autenticado ID: " + userId);
            var component = Qt.createComponent("main.qml");
            var win = component.createObject();
            win.userId = userId;
            win.showFullScreen();
            close();
        } else {
            senhaInput.text = "";
            console.log("Falha na autenticação: Usuário e/ou senha inválidos.");
            lblMsgErro.text = "Usuário e/ou senha inválidos.";
            lblMsgErro.visible = true;
            loginInput.focus = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The **controller.autenticar();** method emits **onAuthenticated"" signal.

Here in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25649200/2195551), the guy says that having a controller declared as a QML Object is not a good practice and shows another way of using a controller.

So, I am asking here: How can I control the QML components (like hiding a text or closing a window) from within C++ controller signal; and so, reach the same result as it was being done within the QML file? For now I can managd things from QML to C++, but I don't know how to do the other way (C++ to QML). For example: setting a text of a Label object.

Comment: I may fail to understand the question entirely, but controlling the state of the UI from C++ side may easily be organized with a bunch of properties in the controller object, with the QML UI state (including the current screen, buttons' enabled states and visibility) being "bound" to those; then, Q_INVOKABLE methods in the controller (like tryAuthenticate(name, pass)) could be invoked in QML button/mouse handlers, triggering controller/backend state change and, potentially, UI state change.

Comment: ...Care should be taken about structuring the bindings in a way making it impossible for things to go wrong, as the QML-side bindings depending on the same controller property are reevaluated (so that UI does not attempt to go through an unanticipated state, potentially breaking things).

Comment: Hey, thanks for commenting. I know how to call methods from QML to C++. What I don't know is how to do the other way. For example, set a label.hidden = true from C++ to QML. In the code above: How could I do the ELSE {} part of onAuthenticated inside C++ code?

Comment: Trick is, to have a QPROPERTY(bool hiden READ hidden NOTIFY hiddenChanged) in the C++ controller, and bind label's `visible` to `!controller.hidden` (roughly), this way it will work automatically, via property change notification mechanism (and will allow the C++ backend to "know nothing" about the frontend, which is the preferred practice).

Comment: Thanks, should I use the same approach to get access to the window the controller controls? For example: I want after authentication, close the window and open a new one.

Comment: May be, basically a Loader could be used to load qml files for the windows based on current values of controller's properties (but watch out for the states the bindings go through during destruction of the previous window, again). Like: `Loader { source: controller.source }` (roughly, sizing and parenting of the created window may require care). I short the "C++ backend dealing with app state changes in response to UI and network events + QML UI which is just a "projection" of the backend's state" approach is both the standard practice, more or less, and the most comfortable one.